# Kendo UI - Insert in the datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have used Kendo Grid in my project to display data. Here to insert grid data in my datasource, I have used the bellow code. But in the bellow code in insert statement I have provided field name of grid and have values assigned to it. For example `AMOUNT: objGridData[idx].AMOUNT`

Hence my requirement is that I need to do insert in my datasource without specifying field name as in future columns of grid might change for example can we use `datasource.add()`.

```
// Inserts Record to the Grid
for (var idx = 0; idx < objGridData.length; idx++) {
var newrec= grid.dataSource.insert(idx, {
           AMOUNT: objGridData[idx].AMOUNT,
           id: objGridData[idx].id,
           PERCENT: objGridData[idx].PERCENT,
           PRODUCT1: objGridData[idx].PRODUCT1,
           PRODUCT2: objGridData[idx].PRODUCT2,
           PRODUCT3: objGridData[idx].PRODUCT3,
           PRODUCT4: objGridData[idx].PRODUCT4,

        });
}
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Either you identify a column by it name or its index. But I would not want to trust on a list to have the very same order all the time. So name it is. If the data in your grid changes, simply update the grid.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can get the property by its name as key.
So

```
var cols = ["percent"];
var newObj = {};
newObj[cols[0]] = objGridData[0][cols[0]];
grid.dataSource.insert(0, newObj);
```

Hope you can do the  rest.